# writing equation in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write equations in a proper form  in Excel-VBA macro. Proper means just like we type equations in Mathematica or in MS word.

But I end up writing like this

x=(-1+(p* h)/τ*y)^(2+1/n)

Any command/clue that can help me writing in a more clear /understandable form. I want this because in my code the equations are very long, and I might make a mistake in writing.
Thank you very much. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nope nope nope this seems impossible to me. An easier solution would be to orginize your ecuation so you can be sure it is correct for example: A=(-1+(p* h)/τ*y) then B=(2+1/n) there for X=A^B

Comment: what do you mean by "more clear / undetstandable form"? Any expression you want to write will have to be written in a single line. If what you want is to make it look "pretty", then consider moving away from MS products, and use LaTex

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for here.  What do you mean by a "*more clear/understandable form*"?

Comment: That's what makes usefull mathematica. vb has not that option. he is asking to see the ecuation as you would write it in paper.

Comment: @bto.rdz: So there is no way to write it except organizing it as you suggested. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It is possible in Excel VBA to store simple equations if you want the equation to be outputted to an Excel Cell but it is not possible to store it in the equation format in the vba editor or Userform and ActiveX control as they don't support multi character formatting

Comment: You can insert an equation into a worksheet formatted as in a textbook by using the Microsoft Equation Object.  From the **Insert** tab in the Ribbon, select Object and the Microsoft Equation 3.0.......there are lots of formatting options.  Sadly, these "equations" can't be executed.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to my query